# How to get a properly indented custom enumerate list (with checklist-style blanks)?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I'm trying to make an enumerated checklist that looks like this:

```
    Paragraph text here that says really cool stuff. Notice how the list after is 
    properly indented

    ___ 1. Thing 1
    ___ 2. Thing 2
    ___ 3. Thing 3

    And the paragraph afterward, with good margins
```

This (though cumbersome) gets pretty close, but for some reason the margin gets messed up:

```
Paragraph text that says really cool stuff.

\begin{enumerate}
\item[\underline{\hspace{0.5in}} 1.]
\item[\underline{\hspace{0.5in}} 2.]
\item[\underline{\hspace{0.5in}} 3.]
\end{enumerate}

And the paragraph after.
```

The output looks like this:

```
    Paragraph text here that says really cool stuff. Notice how the list after is
    NOT PROPERLY INDENTED

___ 1. Thing 1
___ 2. Thing 2
___ 3. Thing 3

    And the paragraph after.
```

I've dinked around a little with [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), but I have the same margin trouble. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dinked around in `enumitem` just a little bit more. Try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[textwidth=3in]{geometry} % so shorter lines wrap
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Some text - a long line so that it wraps and we see the paragraph
indentation

\begin{enumerate}[itemindent=0.5in,
label=\underline{\hspace{0.5in}}\arabic{*}.]
\item Thing 1
\item Thing 2
\item Thing 3
\end{enumerate}

More text, indented as the start of a paragraph. Long enough to wrap.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `itemindent` is hard coded, which is a little ugly and may not be robust enough in some cases.

You could wrap the `enumerate` in your own environment in order not to cut and paste the item options.

Comment: You may have to specify an independent `ref=\arabic*` option to avoid typesetting the "underline" if you do end up using references. The default (without specifying `ref=...`) is to duplicate that of `label=...`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, your example helped me understand some of the enumitem options a bit better.